# Привет всем! помогите с Sublime text

Tags: sublime-text-3

Установила Sublime text. Вбила Package Control, Emmet, MinGW32(base). В переменную среды добавила в Path ;C:\MinGW\bin. Теперь пробую компилировать через CTRL+B. В чем ошибка(что я не настроила? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я не разбираюсь в piton. Но ошибок вроде нет никаких. Может к пути добавить ещё C:\MinGW  ?

Comment: В переменной среды уже указала данный путь(на скрине есть)(((

Comment: Я имею ввиду без папки bin.